# AWS IoT policy not inserting policy variables (iot:ClientId)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, x509certificate, aws-iot

I am attempting to set up Just In Time Provisioning (JITP) as explained in this doc https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/iot/setting-up-just-in-time-provisioning-with-aws-iot-core/ . I have managed to create a script that creates all the CA certificates, registers them with the AWS CLI and attaches a provisioning template to the certificate. When I try to connect a device for the first time the certificate and device are created as normal but the policy I created to attach to the certificate is not inserting the `{iot:clientID}`. I also tried using other variables such as `{iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}` but nothing seems to be working. 
I was able to verify that the code and everything else is working by hardcoding the clientID into my policy template so the only issue seems to be that the variables aren't being inserted.

I thought that maybe this could be because of the IAM role not having enough permissions? At the moment it only has the AWSIoTThingsRegistration, AWSIOTLogging and AWSIOTRulesAction permissions as mentioned in the doc above. Or maybe it's just that a policy cannot used these variables when auto-provisioning devices although there is nothing in the provisioning template docs that suggests that?

My policy for reference:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Publish",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:eu-west-1:ACCOUNTID:topic/PROJECTTOPIC/"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "iot:Connect"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:iot:eu-west-1:ACCOUNTID:client/${iot:ClientId}"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Receive",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:iot:eu-west-1:ACCOUNTID:topic/PROJECTTOPIC/${iot:ClientId}"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Subscribe",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:iot:eu-west-1:ACCOUNTID:topicfilter/PROJECTTOPIC/${iot:ClientId}"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I don't know if it's relevant but here's my provisioning policy too:

```
{
 "templateBody":"{ \"Parameters\" : { \"AWS::IoT::Certificate::Country\" : { \"Type\" : \"String\" }, \"AWS::IoT::Certificate::Id\" : { \"Type\" : \"String\" }, \"AWS::IoT::Certificate::CommonName\" : { \"Type\" : \"String\" } }, \"Resources\" : { \"thing\" : { \"Type\" : \"AWS::IoT::Thing\", \"Properties\" : { \"ThingName\" : {\"Ref\" : \"AWS::IoT::Certificate::CommonName\"}, \"AttributePayload\" : { \"version\" : \"v1\", \"country\" : \"IE\"} } }, \"certificate\" : { \"Type\" : \"AWS::IoT::Certificate\", \"Properties\" : { \"CertificateId\": {\"Ref\" : \"AWS::IoT::Certificate::Id\"}, \"Status\" : \"ACTIVE\" } }, \"policy\" : {\"Type\" : \"AWS::IoT::Policy\", \"Properties\" : { \"PolicyName\" :  \"MYPOLICYNAME\"} } } }",
 "roleArn":"arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNTID:role/MYROLENAME"
}
```

I'm fairly new to using IAM policies so any advice or help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out it was a permissions issue after all. For anyone trying to attempt using a policy template for JITP try adding `AWSIoTConfigReadOnlyAccess` to your IAM role. This isn't required for the usual JITP actions but if you're trying to access the Thing data it is.

Comment: Sorry if my edit came across as sarcastic, that was not my intention. But it is not necessary here to say "thanks" at the bottom of a question. If you want to thank someone for their answer, you should upvote and/or accept it. And besides, "thanks in advanced" is just wrong, it would be "thanks in advance".

Comment: You can also accept your own answer so that others can easily see that the problem is solved.